# Node js require code instead of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I am trying to setup an interface, where I can write one js file that can be used on the server (nodejs) and on the client (javascript).

An example file would be a Vector object, that I would like to use on both the client and the server, as I am creating a multiplayer game.

In node.js, I know that you can use the following syntax to require source files...

```
var Vector = require('./vector');
```

Then you can access its `module.exports` by typing in `Vector`.

The problem here is that for the server I need an extra bit of code at the end of the file...

```
module.exports = Vector;
```

... which is not necessary on the client.

Is it possible to maybe require source code, something like the following?

```
var data = (...) // get data from vector.js file
var Vector = require_code(data + 'module.exports = Vector');
```

If not, there might be another way of doing what I am trying to accomplish.

That might sound a little confusing, but help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [UMDs](http://bob.yexley.net/umd-javascript-that-runs-anywhere/) - Universal Module Definitions.

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["jquery", "underscore"], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
        module.exports = factory(require("jquery"), require("underscore"));
    } else {
        root.Requester = factory(root.$, root._);
    }
}(this, function ($, _) {
    // this is where I defined my module implementation

    var Requester = { // ... };

    return Requester;
}));
```

You'll need to change the name in `root.Requestor` to be the name of your module.  `root` picks up the value of `this` which will be the global object or what you normally call `window` on the browser.

This particular example looks for `jQuery` and `underscore` as example dependencies, but they are easy enough to factor out if you need.